# Помогите завести OxyPlot на Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

Помогите завести OxyPlot на Xamarin. В NuGet есть соответствующий пакет, но он не работает под Xamarin.Forms 5.0. Возникают конфликты, связанные с тем, что OxyPlot пытается использовать .NET.Fraemwork, а весь Xamarin работает под .NET.Standart. Более опытные коллеги предлагали отдельно поставить OxyPlot для Android и отдельно для UWP. А потом сделать в общем проекте кастомный контрол, который использовал бы рендеры отдельно для Android и отдельно для UWP. Поскольку OxyPlot обладает открытым исходным кодом, то все необходимые рендеры там имеются, но, насколько я понимаю, в любом случае в общем проекте необходимо использовать OxyPlot.Core. Может быть кто-то, кто имел дело с OxyPlot подскажет, так ли это на самом деле или же я может быть ошибаюсь.

Также интересно узнать о том, существуют ли какие-то бесплатные альтернативы, которые позволяют выводить несколько графиков на одной координатной плоскости, буду рад увидеть примеры для них.

Comment: Как вы поняли, что он не работает? А вообще разработка выглядит заброшенной лет 5 назад. Вы уверены, что нет альтернатив?

Comment: Попробовал поставить этот пакет, но выяснилось, что для работы некоторых компонентов требуется .NET.Fraemwork, хотя весь Xamarin сейчас работает на .NET.Standart. Попытка создать кастомный контрол со своим рендером под каждую систему, тоже не увенчалась успехом (собственно, хотелось бы именно по этому вопросу посоветоваться с кем-то более опытным, возможно просто что-то делаю не так, но, насколько я понимаю, для работы кастомного контрола, .OxyPlot.Core необходимо подключить не только в проектах отдельных платформ, но и в общем проекте, но возникает конфликт версий, который невозможно уладить)

Comment: Последняя версия действительно вышла в 2017 году. Из бесплатных альтернатив видел только MicroCharts, но не встречал ни одного примера, где на одной координатной плоскости отрисовывали сразу бы несколько графиков. Не утверждаю, что этого нельзя сделать, но единственный пример, который я видел рекомендовал использовать OxyPlot, к тому же не понимаю, как правильно настроить привязки при реализации паттерна MVVM с этим компонентом. Буду рад посмотреть на соответствующие примеры.

Comment: Дополните вопрос новой информацией, его можно отредактировать.